# Triple Cartesian Product with empty set.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I currently stumbled with the following problem.

Find the cartesian product of $\{\emptyset\} \times \{0,\emptyset\} \times \{0,1\}$

My confusion comes from the fact that $\emptyset \times$ (any set)$ = \emptyset$. This I understand.

I do not know however, how it differs when multiplying $\{\emptyset\} \times$ (any set). I am not familiar with how to compute such a cartesian product. I would also this would also be the $\emptyset$.

I know the answer is $\{(\emptyset,0,0) , (\emptyset,0,1) , (\emptyset, \emptyset,0) , (\emptyset, \emptyset, 1)\}$.

Can anyone explain me the difference between computing the $\emptyset \times (any set) and \{\emptyset\} \times $(any set).

I'd also appreciate if anyone could show me how to compute this problem or give me some hints so I can get to the answer.

Edit: I got the answer now. I was overthinking it. Thank you for making a simple observation in the comments

Comment: $\{ \emptyset \}$ is not the empty set! It's a one-element set, whose only element is the empty set.

Comment: Would you know how to compute $\{2\} \times \{0,2\} \times \{0,1\}$ ? Because that's the same situation. Here $\emptyset$ is just another element of a set.

Comment: Thank you, I was overthinking it.